# Is there a fix for styling different components locally?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

So to style this new component I made I've tried wrapping it in a `<div>`, I've tried in-line styling (which is the only styling that works but gets messy), I've tried css modules and I've also tried configuring webpack.config.js file and nothing seems to work. In the config file I can't really change it since it looks different from (test: /.css$/,), This is what it looks like:

```
{
  test: cssModuleRegex,
  use: getStyleLoaders({
    importLoaders: 1,
    sourceMap: isEnvProduction
      ? shouldUseSourceMap
      : isEnvDevelopment,
    modules: {
      getLocalIdent: getCSSModuleLocalIdent,
    },
  }),
},
```

Anything to do with importing styles into a file just doesn't work for some reason. If I somehow make it work it will still clash with my App.js component.

**Blog.css:**

```
h2 {
  font-style: italic;
  color: red;
  font-weight: lighter;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

I want to style the `h2` tag in Blog.js but for some reason it will ALWAYS clash with App.js:

**App.js:**

```
import React from "react";
import { Component } from "react";
import fbook from "./image/fbook.png";
import insta from "./image/insta.png";
import tweet from "./image/tweet.png";
import me from "./image/itsme.png";
import Blog from "./components/Blog.js";
import NewWindowComponent from "./NewWindowComponent";




class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      isNewWindow: false
    }

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }



  handleChange (event) {
    const {name, value} = event.target
    this.setState({name: value})
  }

  handleClick () {
    this.setState({
      isNewWindow: true
    })
  }



  render() {
    return (
      <body>
        <header>
          <h2>ALEX</h2> //clashes with this h2 tag instead
          <div className='nav'>
            <a href="#">ALL</a>
            <a href="#">TRAVEL</a>
            <a href="#">LIFESTYLE</a>
            <a href="#">MUSIC</a>
            <a href="#">VIDEO</a>
          </div>

          <div className="search-box">
            <input type="text"
              className="search-bar"
              name="stuff"
              onChange={this.handleChange}
              value={this.state.value}
              placeholder="Search"
            />
          </div>
        </header>

        <div id="background">
          <div className= "container">
            <h1>HI! I AM ALEX!</h1><hr/>
            <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            
            <NewWindowComponent
              onClose={this.state.isNewWindow}>
              <Blog />
            </NewWindowComponent>

            <button onClick= {this.handleClick}>GO TO BLOG</button> 
            <img className= "my-pic" src={me} alt="pic of me"/> 
          </div>
        </div>

        <footer>
          <div className="icons">
            <img className ="f-book" src={fbook} alt="Facebook"/>
            <img className ="tweet" src={tweet} alt="Twitter"/>            
            <img className ="insta" src={insta} alt="Instagram"/>
          </div>

          
          <p>© 2021, Designed by not finished </p>
        </footer>
      </body>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

**NewWindowComponent.js:**

```
import { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class NewWindowComponent extends Component {
  containerEl = document.createElement('div');
    
  externalWindow = null;
    
  componentDidMount() {
    this.externalWindow = window.open('', 'NewWindowComponent');
  
    if (this.externalWindow) {
      this.externalWindow
        .document
        .body
        .appendChild(this.containerEl);
      this.externalWindow.onunload = () => this.props.onClose();
      }
    }
  
    render() {
      return ReactDOM.createPortal(this.props.children, this.containerEl);
    }
  }

  export default NewWindowComponent
```

**Blog.js:**

```
import React from "react"
import { Component } from "react";
import "../components/Blog.css";

class Blog extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
          
        }
       
    }


  render() {
    const myStyle = {
      fontStyle: 'italic',
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      color: 'red',
      textAlign: 'center',
      position: 'relative',
      fontSize: 20
    }

    const scrim = {
      backgroundColor: 'black'
    }

    const woah = {
      lineHeight: 1.5,
      fontSize: 20
    }

    return (
      <body>
        <div className = "cool">
            <header>
                <div style={scrim}className="background">
                <h2>Welcome to my Blog!</h2>
                </div>
            </header>

            <div id="background">
            <div className= "container">
            <h2>About me I guess...</h2><hr/>
            <p style={woah}>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.           </p>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    )
  }
}
export default Blog
```

Comment: please complete the first sentence of your question. Could you please share an example of your complete configuration in a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io) or via github link?

Comment: Here's the codesandbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/kptkr All I'm trying to do is use a style sheet in my Blog.js component.

Answer (score 0):

CSS is global to the document. I suppose you just need to bump the CSS selector specificity in your `Blog.css` file.

Given the `Blog` component code:

```
class Blog extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  render() {
    const scrim = {
      backgroundColor: "black"
    };

    const woah = {
      lineHeight: 1.5,
      fontSize: 20
    };

    return (
      <body>
        <div className="cool">
          <header>
            <div style={scrim} className="background">
              <h2>Welcome to my Blog!</h2>
            </div>
          </header>

          <div id="background">
            <div className="container">
              <h2>About me I guess...</h2>
              <hr />
              <p style={woah}>
                "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do
                eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut
                enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris
                nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
                in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat
                nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,
                sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.{" "}
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    );
  }
}
```

#### Without

Here the Blogg.css CSS is "leaking" out and effecting rest of the document.

[image]

#### With more specific selector

You can target elements that are descendants of the `div` with the `"cool"` classname.

index.css

```
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Blog.css

```
.cool h2 {
  font-style: italic;
  color: red;
  font-weight: lighter;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

[image]

[image: Edit is-there-a-fix-for-styling-different-components-locally]

Comment: Wait, for some reason I copied exactly what you did and it's still not applying to Blog.js only. It still clashes with App.js Also that's not how my index.css looks above maybe I forgot to put to import last time here's the "updated" code: https://codesandbox.io/s/blog-kptkr Thx for the help greatly appreciated.

Comment: @iNfam0usColors Your new CSB appears to crash, error "TypeError: this.props.onClose is not a function" in the `NewWindowComponent`.

Comment: I'm sorry you have to leave the new tab open which is NewWindowComponent.js if that's not too much trouble. I was trying to get the button to when clicked, Blog.js pops in a new tab. For now I'm just trying to style Blog.js but every solution I try either ends up clashing with App.js or just straight up doesn't work.

Comment: @iNfam0usColors I have played around with your sandbox, commenting out one or the other, or both, and the UI in the opened window always looks the same. Can you post some screen shots of what it *should* look like, and what you are currently experiencing? It's hard to know what to look at specifically.

Comment: When the NewWindowComponent.js pops up it should look exactly like the picture you sent above. "Welcome to my Blog!" should be centered, red, with font size 20px. That is the same problem I'm having, any style I try to put in and the opened window (which is Blog.js) just doesn't change. The two pictures above is exactly what I want it to look like.

Comment: I'm sorry I think I made a fix to my NewWindowComponent.js for the styling to work: [https://codesandbox.io/s/blog-2-0-kptkr ] Now all I need help with is plugging in the Blog.js in the window that pops up on button click. NewWindowComponent.js was wrong when I looked at it again so maybe that's why the styling wasn't working. I'm sorry for making this confusing I'm still learning React JS. I updated the code, I greatly appreciate your advice.

Comment: @iNfam0usColors The extent of what I know needs to happen is that you need to copy the CSS from your app *into* the new window. I googled and there are a few solutions out there, all pretty similar. This is about the [simplest one](https://codesandbox.io/s/blog-2-0-forked-ccrve?file=/src/NewWindowComponent.js) I found and got working. It's not pretty, for sure, but it gets the styling there.

Comment: @iNfam0usColors This is all a bit outside the scope of your question here in its present form. It seems your question/issue is more about how to style a document in another window.

Comment: Yeah I changed the NewWindowComponent.js to open a new window on button click instead of opening a new tab . The styling issue should be resolved but for some reason when I click the button App.js pops up in the window. So my new question for you is on button click how can I make Blog.js display on the new window? [ https://codesandbox.io/s/vzxvt ]